# Why List<T>.ForEach checks version after loop ends?

Tags: c#, list, foreach

We were looking at source code of [List.ForEach method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,0e5a9cf0a310b9e5,references) and it is implemented as below:

```
public void ForEach(Action<T> action) {
    if( action == null) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
    }
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    int version = _version;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < _size; i++) {
        if (version != _version && BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5) {
            break;
        }
        action(_items[i]);
    }

    if (version != _version && BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
}
```

We could not find a reason why version is checked twice. We think that exception could be thrown instead of `break`. We also think that final check may cause an unnecessary exception if the list is modified by another Thread after the loop has finished, before the check is executed.

Simply why the loop is not implemented like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < _size; i++) {
    if (version != _version && BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
    }
    action(_items[i]);
}
```

Comment: "cause an unnecessary exception if the list is modified by another Thread after the loop has finished, before the check is executed" - which sounds like a bug just waiting to happen if the `ForEach` happens to take a little longer to run. I.e. such code already seems to have a race condition, why should such code not noisily break things, occasionally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The check essentially verifies that the very last call to the action delegate does not change the collection.

Since this is part of the contract, under [remarks in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Modifying the underlying collection in the body of the Action delegate is not supported and causes undefined behavior.

Then this is entirely legal, and the right thing to do.

Additionally, they've postponed the throwing of the exception from inside the loop to the code after the loop to avoid repeating that code which makes sense.

Now, having said that, the code *could* have been written like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < _size; i++)
{
    action(_items[i]);
    if (version != _version && BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
}
```

It is possible that the current look of the code is due to a decompile or similar which duplicates the if-part but not the call to the ThrowHelper.